# Using the concept of fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

### I am trying to learn Fragments

---

***I am using [this tutorial for reference](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial)***

I am trying to execute a simple program from the [tutorial](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial)

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.fragmentsfirstproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,
                                     container, false);

        Button nextButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
        android:text="Click Me !" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**Apparently in the line**::

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**I am getting a error**

```
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity)
```

- Why is this error occurring, can't i use `OnclickListener` in
  `fragments`
- How can i correct myself

Please go easy on answers . i am new to fragments !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the dialog click listener besides a simple click listener.

Implement the method as below for your `Button` Click listener and import `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;` :

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are importing wrong onClickListener 
`import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;` which is used for dialogs..

Try to import..`import android.view.View.OnClickListener;` and set it to button..

and implement that `onClick()` method..

Answer (score 1):

Try to import..import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

and implement

```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following IMPORT statement..

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

And then in ECLIPSE press Ctrl+Shift+o

Remove the implemented onClick() function.

and again override it.

U'll get the correct function.